# C++ Vector Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, overloading

I am trying to find a simple example program that overloads the following operators of a mathematic vector.

```
Constructor  // create

= (equals)     // assign

+; -; +=; -=   // add sub

*; /; *=; /=   // multi divide

++; -- // plus minus

==    // compare
>; >=
<; <=

[]    // access a value
```

Cant seem to find any good simple tutorials. I emphasize the simple because I am only learning this stuff now. If someone could link me or even better program a simple overload for just one of the operators as an example would be incredible!

Comment: When you say "mathematical vector" what actual type is it?

Comment: Like this? http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/

Comment: In future work at uni i got told we will be using "mathematical vector, not STL vector" so not sure if they are same thing or different.

Comment: also if i have to make a 'vector class object' what does that mean? Is the a class that inherits from vector?

Comment: I would think that a "mathematical" vector means a vector of coordinates, not an array of objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few things to know when you write operators, which are not as often used with other functions.

The assign operators, for example, will `return *this` because you change the value of the vector:

```
class v {
public:
  double x_, y_;
  v& operator += (const v& rhs)
  {
     _x += rhs._x;
     _y += rhs._y;
     return *this;
  }
};
```

Another interesting one, the pre `++` and post `++` are different only because of an unused parameter:

```
class v {
public:
  double x_, y_;
  v& operator ++ (); // ++v
  v& operator ++ (int); // v++
};
```

The "equal" (assignment) is another one that is tricky when you use pointers. For a vector, it generally won't be a problem, but if you define a vector V and assign it to itself, you have to be careful:

```
class v {
public:
  double x_, y_;
  v& operator = (const v& rhs)
  {
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
      x_ = rhs.x_;
      y_ = rhs.y_;
    }
    return *this;
  }
};
```

In your case, the `if()` will most certainly not be useful, but think about doing something like this:

```
   delete p_;
   p_ = new foo;
   p_->x_ = rhs.p_->x_;
```

If `&rhs == this`, then the `delete p_` deleted the `rhs` pointer! That means accessing it on the 3rd line is a bug.

The rest should be easy enough to work with. The compare operators return `bool` and are `const`:

```
class v {
public:
  double x_, y_;
  bool operator == (const v& rhs) const
  {
    return x_ == rhs.x_ && y_ == rhs.y_;
  }
};
```

Although, since C++20, you are expected to only declare the three way comparison operator `<=>` which allows the compiler to implement all the other comparison operators for you. This one returns a negative number (smaller: a < b), 0 (equal: a == b), or a positive number (larger: a > b).

*I'm not sure what makes a vector bigger or smaller, I used the length from (0, 0) in this example:*

```
class v {
public:
  double x_, y_;
  int operator <=> (const v& rhs) const
  {
    if(x_ == rhs.x_ && y_ == rhs.y_)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    return length() > rhs.length() ? 1 : -1;
  }
};
```

Except for the `[]` operator. There are two versions of that one:

```
class v {
public:
  // I would imagine you'd use an array but as a simple example...
  double x_, y_;
  double operator [] (int idx) const
  {
    return idx == 0 ? x_ : y_;
  }
  v_ref operator [] (int idx)
  {
    v_ref v(this, idx);
    return v;
  }
};
```

As you can see, the non-constant version of the [] operator returns a reference. This is necessary so you can write something like:

```
r[3] = 7.3;
```

`r[3]` returns that reference, then the assignment of the reference is called with `7.3` as the parameter. (Note that we should probably throw an error if you use 3 as the index when you only have 2 values: 0 and 1--this is not shown here)

```
class v_ref
{
public:
  v *p_;
  int i_;
  v_ref(v *p, int i)
    : p_(p), i_(i)
  {
  }
  operator = (double q)
  {
     // again, I suppose you'd use an array instead!
     if(i_ == 0)
     {
       p_->x_ = q;
     }
     else
     {
       p_->y_ = q;
     }
  }
};
```

Assuming you want some security, the vector pointer could make use of a reference counter so you know whether a main vector object gets deleted before all of its reference objects...

Another note: I would imagine that your constructor will allocate an array of double (or use an `std::vector<double>` type...) If you use new, remember to delete in the destructor and that's when the `if()` in the assignment operator is very important.

Comment: How do i create a Vector Class Object though to implement this stuff in?

Comment: @user2495847 So you don't even have your `vector` class yet? It sounds like you need to start with some basic C++ class tutorials.

Comment: @crashmstr I am being asked to create a Vector Class Object so does that mean create a vector like so...  vector <v> using the code shown above or does it mean to... class myVector : std::vector<int> { ... }; sort of thing?